# Are primarily security questions about Google accounts on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

WebApps.SE ostensibly replaces Google support forums, such as the [Google Photos Help Centre](https://support.google.com/photos/) and the [Google Drive forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/drive). Stack Exchange is preferable, because answers are better quality (due to gamification with the reputation points system), comments are out of the way, and questions don't automatically become closed after a while.

So, I think people interpret WebApps more as a *replacement* support forum for Google products, and not so much a site that is exclusively focused on website applications. Thus, questions about security, such as [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126219/109353) creep in, which are not actually to do with web applications, but it just seems to fit here because it's about Google products. I wanted to flag this question to be moved to security.stackexchange.com, but that site wasn't listed as a migration option.

The purpose of this meta post is to ask: Is the Stack Exchange network as a whole trying to separate security questions about Google accounts from web apps questions about Google products, or are we just going to overlap with [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), and end up becoming a one-stop solution for all Google questions? I guess a lot of WebApps.SE users would know an answer to security questions, but I would have thought the expertise lies over there.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it would not be on-topic on [Security.SE] at all.  The OP says `I think this is a critical security issue`, but the remainder doesn't really warrant it being directed to experts in security (who are not necessarily *computer* security people, as a whole) when it's really about using one particular feature of a specific application.

Comment: aaaand, the question was [duplicated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126552/109353)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the Stack Exchange network as a whole trying to separate security questions about Google accounts from web apps questions about Google products, or are we just going to overlap with IT Security, and end up becoming a one-stop solution for all Google questions?

Definitely the former. This site is for questions about using web applications. We, as a matter of course, close/migrate Android questions, or questions about using Chrome for instance, so other non-web app questions about Google should be treated just the same.

As the question you've cited is about the Backup & Sync software Google offers, it would seem to be on-topic at [Super User](https://superuser.com). I've voted to migrate it there.

For future reference, if you see a question that is clearly off-topic *here*, and would be clearly on-topic *on another site*, use the "in need of moderator intervention" and make your case for migration. (Moderators can migrate to any site.) If it's simply off-topic here and not an excellent question for another site, simply vote to close it with a custom off-topic reason.

Comment: It's useful to clarify where Backup and Sync questions belong, as you have done, because those questions appear here a lot.

Comment: We've done that for other things (see [tag:dropbox]), but as there's no [google-backup-and-sync] tag here, there's really no place to add any extra guidance.