# A regular user failed to flag a question that was duplicated a week ago

Tags: discussion, scope, migration, flagging, exact-duplicates

I have been unfairly treated. I spent an hour of my time to do research to answer [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126219/109353), so I even missed the lecture I had that morning, because I wanted to sort this out and give a thorough answer (considering all the alternatives). After testing what clicking "Sign out of all other web sessions" under Gmail's "Last account activity" does, I needed to find out what enabling two-step verification does, so I created a new Google account and went through the process of syncing it with a computer on Backup and Sync. Not to mention testing what effects those have on being signed in to Chrome.

I felt doubtful whether the question was appropriate on Web Apps though, so I [opened a meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4628/109353) to discuss it. Although I thought it belonged on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com), the advice was that questions about Google's Backup and Sync program belong on Superuser.com, so [ale](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) flagged it for migration, and it [was moved to Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/1415822/386552).

Only four days after I posted that meta post, the question [was duplicated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126552/109353). I couldn't flag it as a duplicate, as the duplicate was now on a different site, so I followed ale's advice and flagged it for migration to Superuser.

However, I'm posting this meta post because I think [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471) didn't act ethically by answering that question. He/she is a regular user. I only follow [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) and [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) questions, but user0 is very active in those questions. They surely would have seen the previous question... and **possibly copied my answer**, instead of flagging the question. It is not impossible that they saw my previous meta post.

What is particularly annoying is that they got 25 reputation points, whereas I got zero from my answer on the first question, but I'm the one who spent an hour doing research in order to answer the question.

If this kind of dynamic occurs on this site, my incentive to put in hard work with answering questions is slim.

Comment: Note: the newer one was posted at 14:32 and the older one was migrated at 23:45 on the same day, so there were at least 9 hours to assume if user0 didn't notice if it's a duplicate or not. Now, I don't know if your answer on the older one got upvoted or accepted before being migrated, but if it's not, then *the question couldn't be closed as a duplicate*. Regular users can only vote to close as a duplicate if the question is posted by the same user (which is not in this case), or if the question has an upvoted/accepted answer (I can't tell).

Comment: I agree that the question can't be closed as a duplicate, but the purpose of my previous meta post was to clarify what should happen with questions about remotely signing out of Backup and Sync. Thus, it should be migrated to Superuser, but now Superuser is getting duplicate questions from our site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything has now been migrated to Superuser.  I have voted to close the second question as a duplicate of the first there.  All of the answers migrated over.

We could certainly debate the decisions that were made, but there were no actual rules broken here, and as such, no action will be taken beyond what has already happened.

Comment: Thank you. My intention wasn't to have a go at user0, it was just to make a stronger point about questions pertaining to this topic (remotely signing out of Backup and Sync). Hopefully the pair of my meta posts will contribute towards guiding what users in this community should do when they see questions like this in future. :)

Comment: @ahorn Much better to use Meta constructively as you have than to go off and try to take matters into your own hands, so I applaud that.  I get that the loss of reputation points and your time and diligence was frustrating, but there will be other opportunities that come along for sure!